# When i try to run makemigrations command in django it gave me an error

Tags: django, migration, settings, makemigrations

When i try to run makemigrations command in django it gave me an error:

`TypeError: _getfullpathname: path should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not list`

Help me to resolve this issue.

This is my static root and media roots all stuffs:

```
# settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')]
MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`STATIC_ROOT` and `MEDIA_ROOT` shouldn't be a list and that's why Django is complaining. You should define them like so:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_root')
```

You can check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#media-root) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#static-root)

Comment: And when more, Where can i check the migrated models data. Like GUI tool like xampp or any command to show the models in cmd or any other.